# iOS Mantle and CLLocation

Tags: ios, iphone, json

This is probably an easy question but if I have JSON that contains both a latitude and longitude value how do I convert that to be a CLLocation property for the corresponding class?

e.g. JSON

```
{
            "Company_ID" = 1;
            "Company_Name" = "Test Company 1qq";
            Credits = 80;
            "Site_ID" = 42;
            "Site_Latitude" = "-37.813986";
            "Site_Longitude" = "144.970637";
            "Site_Name" = Melbourne;
        }
```

and the Model:

```
@interface SiteModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *identifier, *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *siteLocation;

@end
```

Comment: Check out [this issue](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle/issues/44) on GitHub, asking the same question.